# Node.js Mysql Connection Terminated

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm trying to insert a basic form into my database to learn how node works, but I keep getting a fun little error returned..

```
error when connecting to db: { [Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.] fatal: true, code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST' }
```

I have a wrapper for disconnection, but that doesn't seem to help either.

`SELECT * FROM player` returns nothing in `mysql` as well, so nothing is being inserted.

Here is my server.js file: (I omitted connection credentials of course)

```
var connection;

function handleDisconnect() {
    connection = mysql.createConnection(db_config); 
    connection.connect(function(err) {              
        if(err) {                     
            console.log('error when connecting to db:', err);
            setTimeout(handleDisconnect, 2000); 
        }                                
    });                             
    connection.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('db error', err);
        if(err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') { 
            handleDisconnect();              
        } else {              
            throw err;      
        }
    });
}

handleDisconnect();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.post("/post",function(req,res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    res.send("Username is: "+req.body.user+".");
    var post  = {
        name:req.body.user,
        password:"testing",
        email:"fake@email.com"
    };
    connection.query("INSERT INTO player VALUES ?",post,function(err,result) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(result);
    });

});
app.listen(80, function() {
        console.log("Server running on port 80");
});
```

Why is my connection being severed?

Comment: Look like it's not connect at all. Are you sure `con.connect()` is called? Do you see `Re-connecting lost connection:` in the console?

Comment: It's not triggering because the error is fatal, and your answer jsut caused a duplicate Handshake error

Comment: Updated my question to a the code `node-mysql` suggested but still the same issue

Comment: `error when connecting to db:` Are you sure MySQL server is fine? and your `db_config ` is correct? Is there firewalls on your mysql server?

Comment: Turns out my `mysql` username was root instead of what I set it. I didn't `sudo` properly :9

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
con.connect();
```

before `app.listen(80...` should fix the problem.